# A finite metric space is not a $T_1$ space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For some reason, I started to think about finite metric spaces (i.e. a set with finite cardinality together with a metric) and wondered if they satisfy the $T_1$ property, i.e. every singleton is closed. I concluded that its not.

#### Proof

Let $X = (\{x_1, x_2, ...x_n\}, d)$ be a metric space with $n\ge 2$. Let $d_{min}$ denote the smallest distance between two distinct points, i.e.
$$d_{min} = \min\{ d(x,y) \ |\ x,y \in X \land x\neq y\}$$

Then, for any $0< \epsilon < d_{min}$ and $x\in X$, we have that $B_d(x, \epsilon) = \{x\}$. Hence $\{x\}$ is open.

#### Conclusion (Wrong !)

There is no finite metric space that is a $T_1$ space.

Is this correct?

#### Correction

Singletons are indeed open, but that does not necessarily mean they are not closed. Since $X - \{x\}$ it is the union of open sets, $X - \{x\}$ is open, hence $\{ x\}$ is closed.

#### Conclusion

Every finite metric space is a $T_1$ space.

Comment: Sets are not doors.

Comment: Why do you think an open set cannot be closed? Any set in a finite metric space is open and closed.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: In fact it's trivial to show that singletons are closed in _any_ metric space...

Comment: Any metric space is $T_1$, there is nothing particular with finite metric spaces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nothing is open. The OP initially made a wrong conclusion, but corrected it in an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you already know that your (initial) conclusion is not correct. Just because a singleton $\{x\}$ is open doesn't mean it is not closed.

In fact, any metric space, finite or not, is $T_1$. Because every point is closed. This follows almost trivially from the sequential description of closed sets in a metric space, because there is only one sequence fully contained in a singleton, namely a constant sequence.

Comment: In fact, any metric space is a Hausdorff space.